# how to avoid runserver freeze when database connection error in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to intentionally create `django.db.utils.OperationalError` to make a functionality where the server can handle the requests regardless of improper connection to database, but after running py manage.py runserver command, the terminal is logging the following messages and froze, if I try to send a request using postman, the server is not accepting those requests.

I tried to create a file called runserver.py in `app_name.management.commands` and it looks like this

runserver.py

```
from django.core.management.commands.runserver import Command as RunserverCommand
from django.db import connections
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Command(RunserverCommand):
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    self.check_database_connection()
    super().handle(*args, **options)

def check_database_connection(self):
    try:
        with connections['default'].cursor():
            logger.info("Database connection successful")
    except OperationalError as e:
        logger.error("Database connection error: %s", e)
        logger.error("Skipping database-related initialization steps.")
```

when I run `py manage.py runserver` it is showing above logs, but then the server showing again the default messages and got froze again

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\vanum\Desktop\ACADEMICS\Web Development\letsbloom\server> py 
manage.py runserver
Database connection error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: 
Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused 
(0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Continuing application execution without database connection.
File "C:\Users\vanum\Desktop\ACADEMICS\Web Development\letsbloom\.venv\Lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner  
return func(*args, **kwargs)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\vanum\Desktop\ACADEMICS\Web Development\letsbloom\.venv\Lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\vanum\Desktop\ACADEMICS\Web Development\letsbloom\.venv\Lib\site- 
packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect  
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 
failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)    
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
    connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection 
    refused (0x0000274D/10061)
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I want to skip the database connection error here which is `django.db.utils.OperationalError` and want to handle it later and send an error message to the user when a he sends a request to the server by using an Exception block for `django.db.utils.OperationalError`

views.py

```
@api_view(["PUT"])
def bookUpdateAPIView(
    request: Request, 
    bookId: int
) -> JsonResponse:
    try:
        if request.method == "PUT":
            try:
                data = loads(request.body)
                book = Book.objects.get(bookId = bookId)
                serializer = BookSerializer(book, data = data)
                if serializer.is_valid():
                    serializer.save()
                    return JsonResponse({
                        "status": "success",
                        "info": "Book details updated successfully",
                        "data": serializer.data
                    }, status = 200)
            
                else:
                    raise serializers.ValidationError(
                        detail = '; '.join('; '.join(errors) for errors in 
                        serializer.errors.values())
                    )
        
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({
                    "status": "error",
                    "info": f"Book with bookId {bookId} not found",
                }, status = 404)
        
            except serializers.ValidationError as e:
                return JsonResponse({
                    "status": "error",
                    "info": e.detail[0]
                }, status = 400)
        
    except (OperationalError, DatabaseError) as e:
        # Handling an error in case of a database connection issue.
        return JsonResponse({
            "status": "error",
            "info": "Database connection error",
        }, status = 500)

    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({
            "info": "An unknown error occurred, please try again later",
            "status": "error"
        }, status = 500)
```

Comment: Hate to nitpick but many try and except blocks. You can refine this.

Comment: In development, exceptions are allowed to crash the dev server but not in production.